# Setting Permissions for Views on a List

Tags: list, permissions

I'm working on a solution that will allow users submit requests to the finance department by area (A.Fixed Assets, B.Payroll, C.Accounts receivable, etc).

This is the situation:

- **Users can only see tickets they've submitted** (I achieved this by
  going to Settings > Advanced Settings > and selecting the 'Read items
  that were created by the user' radio button)
- **The Area Responsible can only see tickets submitted to his/her area** (Payroll, Accounts Payable, etc)

So basically if an user submits a ticket about a payroll issue, when he goes to the main list **he should only be able to see his tickets** (regardless of the area value) AND the area responsible when going to the same list, **should view all the tickets created under/to his area.**

Is there a way that I can set group permissions for list views? and is this the right way to go?

I created a quick drawing to illustrate the issue:

[image]

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change the setting back (Read items that were created by the user) and instead use view settings and handle all of this through filters.

Filters allow you to restrict who can see different items in a list/library. By using "[Me]" on a person field it will restrict the view to show only items with the current user in that field (For example filter by CreatedBy equals [Me]).

To set a Manager to view all submissions for a section you will need a second list (List B) that contains a person column with the managers name and a field with the section (just use the default title field)

Using a workflow set an additional person field in List A to the value of the List B person field based on the sections being the same (or you could make list A section column a lookup column onto List B section column, this is the better solution imo).

Now you can finish the view by adding in an additional filter to check if the section manager is the current user (or sectionManager = [Me])

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a View based on your Area and edit that page and set Audience Targeting for Each View. This will not allow any one else to view the items other than the name given in Audience Targeting field.

So create three views based on each area filter and give audience targeting for each view by editing the web part. Hope you are aware of Audience targeting.

Also as Roland mentioned removed the settings(Read Items that were created) and have it handled through a different view where CreatedBy equals{Me}